# Recrear BD usando NetCore 2.0 Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, netcore

Hola amigos necesito de su ayuda para poder resolver    un problema que tengo, explico tema.

Tengo un proyecto una APi creada con C# usando NetCore 2.0 y entity framework en su momento se hizo uso de scaffolding para crear el modelo y poderlo usar; con el tiempo este proyecto se dejo ahora que lo retomo no tengo la BD necesito recrear la BD en SQL Server.

Necesito saber que método puedo usar y como hacer para poder recrear la BD desde el modelo que tengo mi proyecto adjunto algunas fotos del proyecto por si alguien me puede aportar la solución quedare muy agradecido.

[Código Proyecto](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KBTvqCj_DWeCUbD7PAuJEAHkaTKpIjmG/view?usp=sharing)

[image: Proyecto APi Modelo]
[image: Contexto Modelo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puesto que veo que ya tienes tu DBContext practicamente configurado por el scaffold con el que la generaste, puedes intentar usar el sistema de migraciones que usa EF, asignas en Startup.cs de donde va a tomar el assembly para las migraciones

```
services.AddDbContext<bdEncuestasContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("default"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("CoreAEncuestas")
    ));
```

despues abriendo el Package Manager Console generas tu migracion inicial (con el nombre que tu quieras), que en si va a generar el codigo para la base de datos.

Eso si, recuerda que debes de tener como target en la consola el projecto donde se encuentren las migraciones (El cual lo puedes cambiar en la parte superior de la consola).

```
Add-Migration InitialMigration
```

te va agenerar un archivo de migracion que se vera mas o menos asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ya una vez generado puedes hacer Update-Database para aplicar los cambios, solo recuerda primero cambiar tu cadena de conexion a tu LocalHost para que pruebes.

```
Update-Database
```

Yo lo intente con tu proyecto, pero me da un error en cierto punto que es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el que dice que un campo ya existe previamente, por cuestiones de tiempo no puedo buscar en el archivo de migracion el conflicto, pero podrias buscarlo y solucionarlo en la migracion o en la configuracion. intentar de nuevo el Update-Databse y si todo sale bien, te generara la base de datos.

Es solo una idea, saludos.

Comment: Hola Stial Manstike tu solución aportada me funciono muchas gracias segui los pasos como los colocaste al principio me genero los mismo erroes pero me di cuenta que era por el modelo tenia unas referencia entre tablas que hacia conflicto pero los solucione y volvi a intentar salio con exito de nuevo gracias